# Can you convert a number in a memory address from a string into an element of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

I have an assignment that requires me to find the sum of a user-defined string of digits, with no space in between them. For example, if I have a string with "1234," the sum would be 10.

Is there a way for me to convert string "1234" into an array with elements {1, 2, 3, 4} so that I can find the total?

Comment: There are! What have _you_ tried?

Comment: I would recommend `std::accumulate` for this task. No need to convert the entire thing into an array of integers, just each character to an integer.

Comment: A string *is* an array.

Comment: Each element in the string is a character, characters are encoded, but you can convert from the character '1' into the value 1 (for that you need only basic math and looking at the character set that you use). You can use that to create an array, or to compute the result on the fly...

Comment: Of course the weekend - people wanting to party away without doing their homework. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A string is an array of chars. That being said, you can parse through the string and convert each char to a digit with atoi or even simpler: c (your char) - '0' (This obtains the numeric value of your char). In the loop, have a sum variable with which you add the result on each iteration. Something that would look like this in code

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; myString[i] != '\0'; ++i)
      sum += myString[i] - '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string str;
  getline(cin,str);
  int sum =0;
  for(int i = 0;i<str.size();i++)
    sum += str[i]-'0';
  //do whatever you want to do with sum..
  return 0;
}
```